How to Fill Missing Timestamps with Interpolated Values in GridDB Time-Series Queries?
I am working on a time-series data analysis project using GridDB. My dataset has irregular intervals, with missing timestamps in some cases. I need to fill these gaps with interpolated values during data retrieval.
Current Setup:
I am using a TimeSeries container in GridDB with the following schema:
timestamp (TIMESTAMP)
value (DOUBLE)

Here’s the Python code to create and populate the container:
import griddb_python as griddb  

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()  
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    notification_member="127.0.0.1:10001",
    cluster_name="defaultCluster",
    username="admin",
    password="admin"
)  

container_info = griddb.ContainerInfo(
    "time_series_data",
    [
        ["timestamp", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
        ["value", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    griddb.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES,
    True
)  
container = gridstore.put_container(container_info)  

# Insert sample data with irregular intervals  
container.put([
    ("2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", 10.0),
    ("2024-01-01T02:00:00.000Z", 20.0)
])

Problem Statement:
I need to retrieve data while filling gaps in the time-series. For example:
For a missing timestamp 2024-01-01T01:00:00.000Z, the value could be the average of 2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z and 2024-01-01T02:00:00.000Z.
Question:
Is there a GridDB-native way to interpolate missing timestamps during query execution, or would this require a custom solution (e.g., post-processing in Python)? If a custom approach is necessary, are there GridDB query features that can simplify this task?
I attempted to retrieve the data using a simple query:
SELECT * FROM time_series_data WHERE timestamp >= TIMESTAMP('2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z')

However, this query only returns the available timestamps in the dataset, skipping the missing ones. I was expecting to find a way to fill the gaps (e.g., 2024-01-01T01:00:00.000Z) with interpolated values or default placeholders during the retrieval process.
The query retrieved the existing data without filling the gaps, leaving the timestamps incomplete. I am unsure if GridDB has a native method for this or if I need to handle it manually after retrieval.
